# PHP como puedo saber si comando DELETE borro el registro?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo que saber si el comando delate borro el registro que le mande a borrar

```
$dato = $_POST['NOM'];
    $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion, "DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE nombre='$dato' ")
```

Sé que el comando me funciona pero necesito saber si el dato que menda se borró

¿Cómo puedo saber si se borró algo o no?

por que si le envió un dato que no existe el la tabal no va hacer nada

quiero saber como saber cuando pasa eso

**Problama**

Confeccionar un programa que permita ingresar el nombre de un curso por teclado y posteriormente efectúe el borrado de dicho registro en la tabla cursos. Mostrar un mensaje si no existe el curso.

**la parte de saber si no existe el curso es la que no se**

Comment: Revisa [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: Revisa la función que te indican. En el peor escenario, también puedes hacer un select buscando el registro y revisar si no obtienes filas que coincidan con la búsqueda

Comment: [Documentación de mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) se devolverá `true` en caso de éxito en la consulta, excepto `SELECT` que se devuelve un objeto mysqli.

Comment: @aeportugal verificar si `query()` devuelve `true` no basta para saber si uno o más registros se eliminaron **realmente**. Considera una consulta del tipo `DELETE FROM laTabla WHERE unaColumna=1;` si en `laTabla` no hay registros donde `unaColumna` sea igual a `1`, la llamada a `query()` devolverá `true` (no hubo error en la consulta), pero no hubo filas borradas. Como bien indica Sal, lo propio es verificar la cantidad de filas afectadas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo trabajo con PDO y utilizo el siguiente código

```
$sql_eliminar = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id=?";
$query_eliminar = $this->conex->prepare($sql_eliminar);
$query_eliminar->execute(array($id));
$total_delete = $query_eliminar->rowCount();
```

Si $total_delete es 1 significa que se eliminó el registro

Comment: PDO es una API distinta de mysqli. En el código de la pregunta se ve claramente que OP está usando mysqli.